# How to display images into a table td using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a table in the database where it contains image,name,location.
I tried to display the name and location, both got displayed. But i struck at how to display the image in the table td. I have almost 4 to 5 rows in the table .

Below is the code which I used.

### HTML:

```
<?php 
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Hotel</th><th>Location</th></tr>";
$i=1;
$html="";
foreach($one as $id => $key):

    $html .= "<tr>";
    $html .= "<td>".$one[$id]."</td>";
    $html .= "<td>".$two[$id]."</td>";
    $html .= "<td>".$three[id]."</td>";
    $html .= "</tr>";
endforeach;
$html .= "</table>";

echo $html;
    ?>
```

### PHP:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hotels');
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
        // mysqli_s(elect_db($link, "hotels");
        $location=$_POST['searchVal'];
        $sql = "select * from rooms where location = '$location'";
        $sqldata= mysqli_query($link ,$sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata)){

            $one[] = $row['name'];
            $two[] = $row['location'];
            $three[] =$row['Image'];


    }


    ?>
```

Output. I am getting some symbols like this:
[image: (check this output here)]

Can anyone please help me out to solve this displaying of image into table.

Comment: where is `$three` defined?

Comment: in php i  have kept $three = $row['Image']

Comment: whee is 2 and 3 now ? this is weird code

Comment: When i use the same code for just $one and $two it worked. the values from data base are displayed in table. Then how can u say that this weird

Comment: I am just asking for a help how to display an image. each row has an images. so in a table for every row i need get the respective images

Comment: but `$two` and `$three` are never defined

Comment: even $one i didn't defined ever.how i did for $one ,same for all. i didn't get any error for that

Comment: what's the data you saved in database for "Image"? also it seems you missed a "$" symbol: $three[id] => $three[$id]

Comment: Mistake  done in this while copying. I added $. still not displaying. I have added an image i.e., data type with longBLOB

Comment: I assume the database has the url of the image, so you should be able to just echo the value of `$three[$id]` as the `src` of an `ìmg` element. But @rtfm is right, your code has no logical structure which makes it very difficult to understand what its doing.

Comment: Once the output. I have added an image. And there is nothing to understand. Here the complete code is available. within the data base there are 3 columns in a "rooms" table. I am able too display the hotel name and location. but which i have added the image into database through phpmyadmin cant be displayed

Comment: what's the relationship between the  two code blocks?

Comment: What i didn't get u

Comment: Ill say the complete scenario. Before it, i have a page which asks for the location. If i type 'hyd' ill get complete hotel rooms available in hyd. So for this purpose i have added a image into the database manually in phpmyadmin. Now when i click on search , i need to get the complete details and display it into tablular form

Comment: Please don't downvote it because it really useful.Until u understand and get the result , it may feel u it is not important. but it is important.

Comment: just think that in ur data base u have  a table with 3 columns, any one of the column must be an image. Just display it to the table in html using php. It helps me a lot . Im trying but I am unable to get it

Answer (score 1):

Actually before I directly uploaded the image into the database.
Now i took a folder and placed the image. And the path of that image is stored in the data based. After retrieving it made me easy to get the image as it checks for the path.

Now i got the image. Thank you so much.

Changes done in code is:

```
**PHP**

<?php 
    session_start();
    $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hotels');
    $three="";
    $one = "";
    $two="";
    if(isset($_POST['sub']))
    {
        // mysqli_s(elect_db($link, "hotels");
        $location=$_POST['searchVal'];
        $sql = "select * from rooms where location = '$location'";
        $sqldata= mysqli_query($link ,$sql);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata)){

            $three[] = $row['image'];
            $one[] = $row['name'];
            $two[] = $row['location'];
        }
    }


    ?>

**HTML**

<?php 

                    echo "<table border='1'>";
                    //echo "<tr><th>Hotel</th><th>Location</th></tr>";
                    $i=1;

                    foreach($one as $id => $key):

                        echo "<tr>";
                         echo "<td>";?><img src="<?php echo $three[$id];?>" height="100" width="100"><?php echo "</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$key."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$two[$id]."</td>";

                        echo "</tr>";
                        $i++;
                    endforeach;
                    echo "</table>";

                        ?>
```

Thank You.